# After Installing Github for Mac Existing Project Reverted to Version About a Month Old

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac

I recently installed Github for Mac.  During the setup process I imported an existing Xcode project, which was open at the time.  Upon doing that Xcode prompted an alert saying that the project had changed and asking if I wanted to re-save.  I opted to resave because I thought the changes it was referring to was the fact that I had just added the project to git.  I didn't think that the actual code files were changed in the process.  Unfortunately what really happend is that the project reverted back to a version from late March, costing me about a month and a half of work.

Does anyone have any suggestions about how I can undo the damage I just caused? I can't figure out why it chose a date in March to revert to.  Perhaps that was the last time I committed the code using Xcode's source control.  There's a version in Time Machine that I can use to restore the project, but that is at least a couple of weeks old.  Before doing that I was wondering if there's a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check what `git log` shows. It will list all commits. If you have a commit, you can restore the source code to that point. (You could do this by, for instance `git reset --hard <committish>`)

(If you have done something really strange, you can also check `git reflog` for commits no longer shown by `git log`, but that does not seem likely.)

Unfortunately it sounds like you last committed in March. In that case Time Machine seems like the best option.

Comment: I suspected that was probably the case.  Thank you for the second opinion.  I'll consider this a hard lesson learned.